# Dismiss The Keyboard - Multiple UITextFields in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

below you'll find my .h & .m files for my primary viewcontroller.

I have 3 questions.

1.) Because I have multiple uitextfields, do I have to set each with their own resignFirstResponder statement ?  and 2.) where would I do that, in what method ?  3.) Is my syntax right for resigning the first responder ?

Also it would be really nice if I could dismiss the keyboard when the user clicks out of the field NOT on hitting the return key!

I know this has been asked and answered before, but to be honest with you i'm still a little confused as to what goes where.

I'm using storyboards, with XCode 5, and iOS 7.

=============================

.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *danceDate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dancePlace;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *danceTerminal;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *danceGate;
```

.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self retrieveFromParse];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // SET DELEGATE HERE
    //
    // if I uncomment 1 of these lines, i'll get an error.
    //
    // _dancePlace.delegate = self; 
    // dancePlace.delegate = self; 
    // dancePlace = self; 

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}


-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: are you fix it by connect the delegate?

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES]; Must work for you

Comment: What error do you get when you uncomment the first line `_dancePlace.delegate = self;` ?

Comment: Have you CTRL dragged from the textfield in Interface Builder to the view controller and set the delegate?

Comment: @Fogmeister let me check...

Comment: Also, what do you get for `NSLog(@"%@", self.dancePlace);` in viewDidLoad?

Comment: this line ->  _dancePlace = self;
generates this WARNING -> "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UITextField *' from 'ViewController *'"

Comment: No, `_dancePlace.delegate = self;` only that line. Not the other two. Look at the error. In your line you are saying, "This text field is this view controller". You need to say, "This text field's delegate is this view controller".

Comment: @Fogmeister checking -> NSLog(@"%@", self.dancePlace);

Comment: No square brackets. Also, fix that line of code. You need to set the delegate.

Comment: @Fogmeister   this line ->    NSLog(@"I AM HERE %@", self.dancePlace); GENERATES ->     2013-10-29 09:42:22.673 iDance[34234:a0b] I AM HERE <UITextField: 0xb673830; frame = (91 51; 108 30); text = '';

Comment: ok finally got it working....self.dancePlace.delegate = self; finally set the damned thing!  oy what the frak!

Comment: Nice one :D yeah, your problem was that you weren't actually setting the delegate. You can do that in code `self.textField.delegate = self` or you can do it in Interface Builder by CTRL dragging from the text field to the view controller (little yellow box) and selecting delegate.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Resigning the textField:
All your textField.delegate should be set as ViewController's object.
And then implement the below delegate method.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

To dismiss Keyboard on tap of the View:
Add a Tap gesture to your ViewController.view as follows:

```
//declare a property to store your current responder
@property (nonatomic, assign) id currentResponder;


//in viewDidLoad:

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resignOnTap:)];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [singleTap release];

//Implement the below delegate method:

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentResponder = textField;
}

//Implement resignOnTap:

- (void)resignOnTap:(id)iSender {
    [self.currentResponder resignFirstResponder];
}
// was missing ; after the call --> [self.currentResponder resignFirstResponder]
    // also in textFieldDidEndEditing set self.currentResponder = nil;
```

Comment: You rock!!!! That nailed exactly what I was looking for!!! Sweeeet!  Thanks a bunch!  And with clear comments telling me exactly what goes where.  :-)  Exactly what a budding newbie needs!

Comment: Glad to know that i was able to help u.. happy coding :)

Comment: spoke too soon.  this only works for 1 field....shouldn't this work for ALL fields ????

Comment: yes. it should.. do one thing..in textFieldDidBeginEditing, put a breakpoint and it console do "po textField.delegate" after that do "po self".. if the address is same it should work, if not then you are not setting the delegate of the textfield properly. you need to check this for each textfield. and u need to set delegate for each textField u add.

Comment: as u have not posted your code where u are adding your multiple textField and the code code is working only for the first textfield, my guess is that you have set the delegate of only the 1st textField. you need to set delegate for each textField you add. Please check this.

Comment: I did post that code, its above.  What you see is what you get.  My understanding was that 

`-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField{

        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
  }`

Should do the trick for all fields....shouldn't it ?

Comment: yes it should provided all your textfield's(danceDate, dancePlace, danceTerminal, danceGate) delegate is set as ViewController. the below code should be there in viewDidLoad 

`self.danceDate.delegate = self

self.dancePlace.delegate = self

self.ddanceTerminal.delegate = self

self.danceGate.delegate = self`

Comment: Didn't have to add a tap gesture recognizer to the view, but thanks!

Answer (score 40):

Try the following:

```
[[self view] endEditing:YES]
```

Comment: Why was this down voted? This is far an away the best way to dismiss the keyboard where you don't have to check individual UITextFields and UITextViews.

Comment: This is the best solution out there !
It should be accepted instead!

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: I've searched for this solution for years, and now there is it. One simple line of code. At last!

Answer (score 5):

This answer works for iOS 7 and arc,

1. dismiss keyboard when user touches return:
   in ViewController add the following action

   > ```
   > -(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
   > {
   >     [sender resignFirstResponder];
   > }
   > ```

next, in main.storyboard select the textField and from the connections inspector 
control + drag "Did End On Exit" event to the view controller.

1. dismiss keyboard when user touches background:
   implement the following method in the ViewController

   > ```
   >  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   >
   >         UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   >         if ([YOUR_TEXT_FIELD isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != YOUR_TEXT_FIELD) {
   >             [YOUR_TEXT_FIELD resignFirstResponder];
   >         }
   >         [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
   >     }
   > ```

Answer (score 4):

```
  -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField{

        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
  }
```

also connect your `UITextField` **Delegate**.

Comment: I tried that.  It doesn't work for me.  And yes I've cleaned the app, reset the whole thing, yadda yadda yadda.  I can NOT get that bit of code to fire.  Secondly it doesn't answer my question, does each named uitextfield need its own resignfirstresponder ???

Comment: you connect the delegate?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I use in my code. It works great and is more efficient than the other answers.

In yourviewcontroller.h add:

`@property (nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;`

Now in the .m file, add this to your ViewDidLoad function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //Keyboard stuff
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapAnywhere:)];
    tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```

Also, add this function in the .m file:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: this is efficient and suggested in `WWDC`

Answer (score 1):

When the `UITextField` in question calls the delegate method of  `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField` it passes itself in as the argument.

So the specific `textField` available as an argument to this method IS the specific one you care about. Within this delegate method, you can just refer to it as "textField".

That means that you should use what Mirko Catalano advised calling `resignFirstResponder` on `textField` rather than on the individual properties like you were doing.

Mirko's suggestion to verify that the delegate is indeed assigned is critical as well. You'll want to make sure that ALL of your UITextFields in the nib or storyboard have their delegate property pointing to File's Owner. Otherwise the delegate message will go nowhere and promptly be ignored!

Answer (score 1):

try to use `self.dancePlace.delegate = self;` instead of `dancePlace.delegate = self;` to set the UITextFieldDelegate. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3 :

```
 //Dismiss keyboard , When touch outside
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```